# What is the best library or method to convert a 24-bit audio to 16-bit audio?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, type-conversion

I am using an audio interface which records audio only with 24-bits per sample. Later, I want to change that to 16-bits per sample.

Which `lib` or `method` can use for this operation? I want to do this in `python-3.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use Python, you could use PySoundFile. Here's a little code snippet:

```
import soundfile

data, samplerate = soundfile.read('old.wav')
soundfile.write('new.wav', data, samplerate, subtype='PCM_16')
```

You should also use soundfile.available_subtypes to see which subtypes you can convert a file to. Here's its sample usage:

```
>>> import soundfile as sf
>>> sf.available_subtypes('FLAC')
{'PCM_24': 'Signed 24 bit PCM',
 'PCM_16': 'Signed 16 bit PCM',
 'PCM_S8': 'Signed 8 bit PCM'}
```